# error when running apache hector-example

Tags: maven, cassandra, classnotfoundexception, hector

I am new in apache Cassandra.

I have installed Apache Cassandra 1.2.5 and Apache Maven. Right now I just want to run the hector-examples posted by zznate in github.com. I am using Mac iOS.

I cloned the hector-examples folder into my local folder, and used the command

```
mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.riptano.cassandra.hector.example.InsertSingleColumn"
```

Built failure.

Is there any steps that I am missing? Thank you very much.

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project hector-examples: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.riptano.cassandra.hector.example.InsertSingleColumn -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project hector-examples: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.riptano.cassandra.hector.example.InsertSingleColumn
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.riptano.cassandra.hector.example.InsertSingleColumn
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>     at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:283)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Comment: Hector was an amazing client for cassandra back in 2010, but now it feels like there are simpler clients out there. Is using hector a requirement for you?

Comment: No. Hector is not a requirement. Could you recommend a simpler clients? At this point my task is just to insert data into cassandra. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with Maven build.
Can you try these steps:

```
mvn clean install
mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.riptano.cassandra.hector.example.InsertSingleColumn"
```

If you are willing to look for other options, astyanax is an excellent choice for querying/ working with cassandra cluster. You can look for examples [here](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax).

Just add the maven dependency or jars in your project and it should be pretty straightforward from there on.

Another option is Datastax java driver. If you've worked with SQL, cassandra has similar querying language called CQL which is amazingly simple and good to use.
Examples available [here](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

And this is how you insert data
`INSERT INTO users
                (user_name, password)
                VALUES ('jsmith', 'ch@ngem3a');`